# Open Jpeg file, write data to file, add iptc tag, add text to image in flight

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm hoping to in-flight edit images that are served through wordpress by leaning on php-fpm

Using nginx I have all images passed through a script

```
server {
    ...
    location ~* \.jpg$ {
      rewrite ^ /jpgproxy.php last;
    }
```

The Jpeg proxy file attempts to do a few things:

1. Open a file and get it as a string
2. Append iptc tags to the file
3. Append a text string to the file
4. Add text to the image (this is where I'm having issues)

This is what I've tried so far:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() 
 && preg_match( '/^\\/([^?]*\\.jpg)(?:$|\\?)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches )
 && file_exists( ABSPATH . $matches[1] )
 && ( $jpg = file_get_contents( ABSPATH . $matches[1] ) ) ) {
    $text ="test";
    
    $iptc = array(
      '2#121' => $text,
      '2#116' => ''
    );
    $data = '';
    foreach($iptc as $tag => $string)
    {
        $tag = substr($tag, 2);
        $data .= iptc_make_tag(2, $tag, $string);
    }
    $jpg = iptcembed($data,ABSPATH . $matches[1]);
    $jpg .= $text;


    //REMOVING THE FOLLOWING 4 Lines will make this work with appending text to file / iptc tag
    $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($jpg);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
    imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0,  "$text", $text_color);
    $jpg = imagecreatefromjpeg(ABSPATH.$im);
    
    
    // output the headers
    header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $jpg ) );
    // disable any sort of cache
    header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' );
    // output the data
    echo $jpg;
}
```

Is there a way for me to write to an image that's loaded as a string or am I forced to write the image to disk as a temp file and then destroy it?

The error for those wondering is:

```
2022/01/12 14:12:46 [error] 6669#6669: *76 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  imagecolorallocate() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/example.com/public_html/jpgproxy.php on line 51PHP message: PHP Warning:  imagestring() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/example.com/public_html/jpgproxy.php on line 54PHP message: PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Empty input file in /var/www/site.com/public_html/jpgproxy.php on line 55PHP message: PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): '/var/www/example.com/public_html/' is not a valid JPEG file in /var/www/site.com/public_html/jpgproxy.php on line 55" while reading response header from upstream, client: 24.233.85.130, server: site.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2022/01/DSC02945-0PBbvKsL_3291595-scaled.jpg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "site.com", referrer: "https://example.com/?p=8"
```

Thanks,

Edit: Special thanks to a comment below from @Torbjörn Stabo:

```
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($jpg);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $text, $text_color);
    imagejpeg($im);
```

Comment: `imagecreatefromstring()`?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo This actually works, can you turn this into something of an answer so I can give you a checkmark?  I was unaware this function even existed.